# .NET ASP webpage inheritance

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, inheritance, web, abstraction

I am new to .NET and ideally want to make several layers of abstraction for making a fairly complex website. Being the first layer handling login, authentication, etc, with another layer handling the built in apps (how they look, predefined functions, database connections), and the lower level will be specific app implementation details.

This favors uniformity as all apps will inherit from one place allowing for easier maintenance and rapid development of all the smaller apps once the overhead abstraction layers handle their responsibilities.

The only problem is I am not 100% sure where to start with .NET ASP webpage inheritance. I tried Google and searching but I may not be looking for the right thing. I am hoping with someone with experience on the matter may direct me towards resources to make this kind of webpage inheritance/abstraction easier!

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Edit:
I also want to add the purpose to my question: Another individual is creating the base of the website which will handle authentication, portal, UI look, etc

I want to make an app base that uses their website framework and adds onto it standards that every app must meet, function library, any addition UI overrides not applicable from portal, etc.

From there a third layer that will directly inherit from the above app base framework (abstraction) and further specify based on the guide lines made.

I appreciate the feedback so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET you have 4 common ways to reuse code/abstractions to serve you application-wide

1. The first way is just using a base page, which will inherit the standard asp.net Page and share the common logic for all of your pages, as explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041305-1.aspx#postadlink)
2. The second way is using a [master page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages): a master page defines a common design (html / css - wise) for all the pages that use it throughout the application. It can also be accessed programmatically by pages that use it, and therefore share a common logic
3. The third way is using an [http module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx): An http module is basically a class, which is responsible for handling an HTTP request before its handled by the expected pages code on the server, and it allows you to add any common logic you want your application to use (such as authentication / authorization handling, getting relevant user information from the DB, etc)
4. [Global.asax](http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.co.il/2008/03/methods-in-globalasax.html): contains application/session wide event handlers, which allow you to handle those events in once place (everything from application starting to a user session ending)

Using modules and base page is the preferred way, if you want to build few applications, sharing common behaviour. A master page can be used as well, of course, if you want them to share the same design as well.

Comment: The code-behind article was very useful, thank you! I see now a combination of this code-behind class abstraction from Page AND use of master page will be needed for my goal. These articles put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a broad question. Welcome to ASP.NET!

I would suggest researching these topics:

- Web page inheritance -> [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx),
- Skinning -> [App_Themes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx),
- separation of responsibilities -> [MVP design
  pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/cc188690.aspx) for the Web Forms platform, or MVC if you have a choice.
- Login, roles -> [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)